# Evaluating the Definite Integral $\int_0^{\pi}\cos^{2n} \theta d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

$$\int_0^{\pi}\cos^{2n} \theta d\theta$$

$$u=\cos \theta \implies du= -\sin \theta d\theta \implies d\theta= -\frac{du}{1-u^2} $$

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{u^n}{1-u^2} du=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{u^n}{(1-u)(1+u)}du$$

I have no idea what to do next, any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: where's $n$ gone?

Comment: $1-u^2=(1+u)(1-u)$. You could use partial fractions.

Comment: @Alex I Fixed it

Comment: @VladimirVargas Okay, let me try.

Comment: @VladimirVargas I cant do it with the power n there, I don't know how to. Can you tell me the form I should write my partial fraction?

Comment: I did it as well and didn't see it clear. Sorry for the bad hint.

Comment: @VladimirVargas hmmmm

Comment: Did you try IBP and a recurrence relation?

Comment: What is IBP? @Alex

Comment: @Alex I did a little searching around the Internet and it Brought me back to this is what you call the recurrence relation, but I don't see how it helps to evaluate the definite Integral .... Recurrence relation to the Indefinite Integral: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114755/prove-that-int-cos-x2n-dx-frac-sin-x-cos-x2n-12n-fra

Comment: I tried Mathematica alpha and Maple but no answer! By the way what integration techniques have you known?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Feel free to use any integration technique you could think of.

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Comment: @Lucian Yes, the answerer says that. So does this mean my Integral is simply $2W_n$ ? Isn't there a different form of answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT

$\int_0^{\pi}\cos^{2n} \theta d\theta=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n} \theta d\theta$

which is Wallis' integral: [integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals)

Comment: Thanks, didn't see this. Appreciate the help!

Comment: So the Answer is $2W_n$ ? Kinda sucks if this is the case.

Comment: Attention: I would say, the answer is $2W_{\color{red}{2n}}$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{2n}\theta\ dt
=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{\binom {2n}k}{2^{2n}}\int_0^{\pi}\cos[2(n-k) \theta]d \theta
=\frac{\pi \binom {2n}n}{2^{2n}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $n=2k$, then
$$ \frac{u^n}{1-u^2}=\frac{u^{2k}}{1-u^2}=\frac{1}{1-u^2}-(1+u^2+\cdots+u^{2(k-1)}). $$
If $n=2k+1$ substitute: $u^2=v$. Then
$$ \int \frac{u^{2k+1}}{1-u^2}du=-\frac{1}{2}\int(1+v+\cdots + v^{2k-1}+\frac{1}{1-v})dv. $$
I hope that I haven't made a mistake, but the idea is seen, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I try to give a proof by Complex analysis method

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$, then $dz=ie^{i\theta}d\theta$, (we can say $d\theta=\frac{dz}{iz}$), and since $\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)$, hence on area $|z|=1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^{2n}\theta d\theta &=\oint_c \left[\frac{1}{2}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)\right]^{2n}\frac{dz}{iz} \\
&=\frac{1}{2^{2n}i}\oint_c \left( z^{2n-1}+\binom{2n}{1}z^{2n-3}+\cdots+
\binom{2n}{k}z^{2n-2k-1}+\cdots+z^{-2n} \right) dz\\
&=\frac{1}{2^{2n}i}\left(2\pi i\binom{2n}{n}\right) \\
&=\frac{1.3.5\cdots(2n-1)}{2.4.6\cdots(2n)}2\pi
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have made an error in your substitution. So let us start again from the beginning. I will assume $n$ is a positive integer.

In the integral we let $u = \cos \theta, du = - \sin \theta \, d\theta$ and this leads to
$$d\theta = -\frac{du}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}},$$
while for the limits of integration $(0,\pi) \mapsto (1,-1)$. So
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\pi \cos^{2n} \theta \, d\theta &= \int_{-1}^1 \frac{u^{2n}}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}} \, du\\
&= 2 \int_0^1 \frac{u^{2n}}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}} \, du,
\end{align*}
as the integrand is even between symmetric limits. Now enforcing a substitution of $u \mapsto \sqrt{u}$ yields
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\pi \cos^{2n} \theta \, d\theta &= \int_0^1 \frac{u^{n - \frac{1}{2}}}{\sqrt{1 - u}} \, du\\
&= \int_0^1 u^{(n + \frac{1}{2}) - 1} (1 - u)^{\frac{1}{2} - 1} \, du\\
&= \text{B} \left (n + \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \right )\\
&= \frac{\Gamma \left (n + \frac{1}{2} \right ) \Gamma \left (\frac{1}{2} \right )}{\Gamma (n + 1)}.
\end{align*}

As
$$\Gamma \left (\frac{1}{2} \right ) = \sqrt{\pi}, \quad \Gamma (n + 1) = n!, \quad \Gamma \left (n + \frac{1}{2} \right ) = \frac{(2n)! \sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2n} n!}.$$
(a proof for this last result can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444967/proving-that-gamma-leftn-frac12-right-frac2n-sqrt-pi22n)) we have
$$\int_0^\pi \cos^{2n} \theta \, d\theta = \frac{(2n)! \pi}{2^{2n} (n!)^2} = \frac{\pi}{2^{2n}} \binom{2n}{n}.$$

Answer (score -2):

See this document (page 5 theorem 2.2): http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/file.php?4,file=57836,filename=507-1088-1-PB.pdf