# Proving that $\Gamma \left(n+ \frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{(2n)!\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2n}n!}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

The proof I am dealing with is worded exactly as follows:

> Prove $\Gamma\left(n+ \frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{(2n)!\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2n}n!}$.

The proof itself can be done easily with induction, I assume. However, my issue is with the domain of the given $n$; granted, the factorial operator is only defined for positive integer values. However, the gamma function, as far as I know, is defined for all complex numbers bar $\mathbb{Z}^-$. I don't think induction will suffice for generalizing the proof for said domain. Would that be necessary, or should I be looking for other methods to tackle the proof?

Comment: if for you the factorial is only defined for integers, then the analytic continuation from integers in general is ambigious. For instance you can add $\sin(\pi n)+n!$ which is change the result for non-integers and leave in unchanged for integers.

Comment: It is probably assumed by the problem that $n$ should be a non-negative integer.

Comment: @pjs36 That sounds reasonable!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative way to prove the cited identity would be to use the integral representation of the $\Gamma$-function with arbitrary arguments :

$$
\Gamma(z)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{z-1}
$$

Specifying $z=n+\frac{1}{2}$ gives us
$$
\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{n-\frac{1}{2}}
$$

Now choosing $t=x^2$ this transforms to

$$
\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})=2\underbrace{\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}x^{2n}dx}_{I_n}
$$

It is easy to show that $I_n=(-1)^n\frac{d^n}{da^n}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-a x^2}\big|_{a=0}=(-1)^n\frac{d^n}{da^n}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4a}}\big|_{a=0}$ where we have used the standard Gaussian integral in the last step.

Furthermore $\frac{d^n}{da^n}\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}(2n-1)!!=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n}}\frac{2n!}{n!}$.

Putting everything together, we obtain

$$
\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2n}}\frac{2n!}{n!}
$$

as desired.

Answer (score 17):

We can also exploit the fact that $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ to obtain
\begin{align*}
\Gamma\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right)
& =\left(n-1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(n-1+\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
& =\left(n-1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(n-2+\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(n-2+\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
& = \ldots
= \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(n-\frac{3}{2}\right)\dots \ \frac{1}{2}\ \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
& = \frac{(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots1}{2^n} \cdot \Gamma\left( \frac{1}{2}\right) \\
& =\frac{(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)(2n-4)\cdots1}{2^n(2n-2)(2n-4)\dots2} \cdot\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{2}\right) \\
& =\frac{(2n-1)!}{2^{2n-1}(n-1)!}\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)\\
& =\frac{2n!}{2^{2n}n!}\sqrt{\pi}.
\end{align*}