# Binomial expansion of $\sqrt{1-x}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $$\int_0^1x^{n-2}\sqrt{x(1-x)}dx=-\pi c_n, n=2,3,...$$
where $c_n$ is the coefficient of $x_n$ in the binomial expansion of $\sqrt{1-x},|x|<1$

$ (1 + x)^n = 1 + \frac{n}{1}x + \frac{n(n-1)}{1*2}x^2 + ... $

$c_n=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(\frac{1}{2}-i)/{n!}$

I guess I will have to do a contour integral to calculate the left-hand side.

Comment: are you sure you want those bounds on your integral?

Comment: Yes from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: so you want the straight line from 0 to 1 in the complex plane?

Comment: I'm doing a real integral but that should be calculated using a contour integral in the complex plane.

Comment: I see, this is a bit confusing as usually people use $z$ to denote a complex number.

Comment: I will change it back to $x$

Comment: Please add some actual attempts and clarify this point: to use contour integrals is an explicit request or anything goes? I am asking because both the mentioned integral and $c_n$ can be computed through the Beta and $\Gamma$ functions.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, Can you explain how to compute them using Gamma? I really have no idea where to start.

Comment: How would you do this with contour integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Beta and $\Gamma$ functions:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}x^{n-2}\sqrt{x(1-x)}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}x^{n-3/2}(1-x)^{1/2}\,dx =B\left(n-\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{3}{2}\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(n-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\,\Gamma\left(\tfrac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+1\right)}$$
so the LHS equals $\frac{1}{n!}\,\Gamma\left(n-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac{3}{2}\right)$. On the other hand $\Gamma\left(n-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)=\left(n-\tfrac{3}{2}\right)\,\Gamma\left(n-\tfrac{3}{2}\right)$, hence:
$$ \Gamma\left(n-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac{3}{2}\right)=\left(n-\tfrac{3}{2}\right)\,\Gamma\left(n-\tfrac{3}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac{3}{2}\right)=\Gamma\left(\tfrac{3}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(n-\tfrac{2k+1}{2}\right) $$
where the RHS equals (by setting $k=n-i$)
$$ -\pi\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}-j\right)$$
as wanted.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}x^{n - 2}\root{x\pars{1-x}}\dd x & =
\int_{0}^{1}x^{n - 3/2}\pars{1 - x}^{1/2}\,\dd x =
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{{%
\Gamma\pars{n - 1/2}\Gamma\pars{3/2} \over \Gamma\pars{n - 1}}}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[1cm]
c_{n} & \equiv \bracks{x^{n}}\root{1 - x} = {1/2 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n} =
{\pars{1/2}! \over n!\pars{1/2 - n}!}\,\pars{-1}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
{\Gamma\pars{3/2} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 1}\Gamma\pars{3/2 - n}}\,\pars{-1}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
{\Gamma\pars{3/2} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 1}\pars{\pi/\braces{\Gamma\pars{n - 1/2}\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{n - 1/2}}}}}\,\pars{-1}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \pi}\,
\bbox[#ffd,10px]{\ds{%
{\Gamma\pars{n - 1/2}\Gamma\pars{3/2} \over \Gamma\pars{n - 1}}}}\,
{1 \over n\pars{n - 1}}\label{2}\tag{2}
\\[1cm] 
& \stackrel{\eqref{1}\ \mbox{and}\ \eqref{2}}{\implies}\,\,\,
\bbx{\int_{0}^{1}x^{n - 2}\root{x\pars{1-x}}\dd x =
\pi n\pars{n - 1}c_{n}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

As @Jack mentions in the comments, your integral can be evaluated using the Beta and Gamma functions.

Here
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 x^{n - 2} \sqrt{x(1 - x)} \, dx &= \int_0^1 x^{(n - \frac{1}{2}) - 1} (1 - x)^{\frac{3}{2} - 1} \, dx\\
&= \text{B} \left (n - \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2} \right )\\
&= \frac{\Gamma \left (n - \frac{1}{2} \right ) \Gamma \left (\frac{3}{2} \right )}{\Gamma (n + 1)}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 n!} \Gamma \left (n - \frac{1}{2} \right ),
\end{align*}
where we have made use of the facts that $\Gamma (\frac{1}{2}) = \sqrt{\pi}$ and $\Gamma (n + 1) = n!$.

Now, as
$$\Gamma \left (n + \frac{1}{2} \right ) = \left (n - \frac{1}{2} \right ) \Gamma \left (n - \frac{1}{2} \right ),$$
then
$$\Gamma \left (n - \frac{1}{2} \right ) = \frac{1}{(n - 1/2)} \Gamma \left (n + \frac{1}{2} \right ).$$
Now it can be readily [shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444967/proving-that-gamma-leftn-frac12-right-frac2n-sqrt-pi22n) that
$$\Gamma \left (n + \frac{1}{2} \right ) = \frac{(2n)! \sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2n} n!}.$$
Thus
$$\Gamma \left (n - \frac{1}{2} \right ) = \frac{1}{(n - 1/2)} \frac{(2n)! \sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2n} n!},$$
and the integral becomes
$$\int_0^1 x^{n - 2} \sqrt{x(1 - x)} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{(2n - 1) 2^{2n}} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} = \frac{\pi}{(2n - 1) 2^{2n}} \binom{2n}{n} = -\pi c_n,$$
and implies that
$$c_n = -\frac{1}{2^{2n}(2n - 1)} \binom{2n}{n}, \quad n = 2,3,4,\ldots$$

Now, from the binomial expansion for $\sqrt{1- x}, |x| < 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{1 - x} &= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n} x^n\\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\frac{1}{2}!}{(\frac{1}{2} - n)! n!}\\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 \Gamma \left (\frac{3}{2} - n \right ) n!}\\
&= -\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n - 1) 2^{2n}} \binom{2n}{n} x^n\\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty c_n x^n,
\end{align*}
where
$$c_n = -\frac{1}{2^{2n}(2n - 1)} \binom{2n}{n},$$
since
$$\Gamma \left (\frac{3}{2} - n \right ) = \frac{(-1)^{n - 1} 2^{2n - 1} (2n - 1) n!}{(2n)!} \sqrt{\pi}. \tag1$$

---

**Addendum**

Here is a proof of (1). To prove the result we will make use of the following result for the Gamma function
$$\Gamma (x + 1) = x \Gamma (x) \quad \Rightarrow \quad \Gamma (x) = \frac{\Gamma (x + 1)}{x}.$$
Repeated application of the above result we see that
\begin{align*}
\Gamma \left (\frac{3}{2} - n \right ) &= \frac{\Gamma \left (\frac{2n + 1}{2} - n \right )}{\underbrace{\left (\frac{3}{2} - n \right ) \left (\frac{5}{2} - n \right ) \cdots \left (\frac{2n - 1}{2} - n \right )}_{(n - 1) \,\, \text{terms}}}\\
&= \frac{\Gamma \left (\frac{1}{2} \right ) 2^{n - 1}}{(-1)^{n - 1} (2n - 3) (2n - 5) \cdots 3 \cdot 1}\\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n - 1} 2^{n - 1} \overbrace{(2n - 2)(2n - 4) \cdots 2}^{(n - 1) \, \, \text{terms}}}{\underbrace{(2n - 2)(2n - 3)(2n - 4) \cdots 2 \cdot 1}_{(2n - 2) \,\, \text{terms}}} \sqrt{\pi}\\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n - 1} 2^{n - 1} \cdot 2^{n - 1} (n - 1)!}{(2n - 2)!} \sqrt{\pi}\\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n - 1} 2^{2n - 2} 2n (2n - 1) n!}{n (2n)!} \sqrt{\pi}\\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n - 1} 2^{2n - 1} (2n - 1) n!}{(2n)!} \sqrt{\pi}, 
\end{align*}
as required to prove.