# Expression for the $\Gamma(\frac{m+n}{2}+1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, factorial, gamma-function, products

I know the expression for $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+n)$ as found in here
[Proving that $\Gamma \left(n+ \frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{(2n)!\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2n}n!}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444967/proving-that-gamma-leftn-frac12-right-frac2n-sqrt-pi22n) .
To me, even an expression for $\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ it gets complicated. Any idea how to understand the simpler one in order to extend it to the case where both $m$ and $n$ are involved?

If I started this $\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)=(\frac{n}{2})!=(\frac{n}{2}-1)    (\frac{n}{2} -2)\cdots  \sqrt{\pi}$ this gives me no simple expression or something .

Comment: I was starting to write an answer, but then I saw the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1445004/602049) to your linked question basically already does this. As you can see, by using your expression and adding appropriate factors to the numerator & denominator to get the factorials, you end up with the correct final result.

Answer (score 1):

$$\Gamma\left(\frac{m+n}{2}+1\right)\\ =\Gamma\left(\frac{m+n+2}{2}\right)$$
[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function#integers) gives the formula:
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\cdot\left(x-2\right)!!}{2^{\frac{x+1}{2}}},\ for\ x\in\mathbb{N}$$
For some positive integer $x$, where $!!$ is the double factorial. We can now substitute $x=m+n+2$ to expand our original equation into the form:
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\cdot\left(m+n+2-2\right)!!}{2^{\frac{m+n+2+1}{2}}},\ for\ m+n+2\in \mathbb{N}\\ =\frac{\left(m+n\right)!!}{2}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2^{m+n+1}}},\ for\ m+n+2\in \mathbb{N}$$
However, simplifying the expression further requires splitting the equation into two. [WolframAlpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) gives the formula:
$$\frac{x!}{x!!}=(x-1)!!$$
As well as:
$$(2x)!!=2^x\cdot x!,\ for\ x=0,1,\cdots$$
Together, we can say that for odd $x$:
$$x!!=\frac{(x+1)!}{(x+1)!!}=\frac{(x+1)!}{2^\frac{x+1}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)!}=\frac{(x+1)!}{2^\frac{x+1}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\cdot\left(x+1-2\right)!!}{2^{\frac{x+1+1}{2}}}\right)}=\frac{(x+1)!}{\left(x-1\right)!!}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$
Reiterating this process $x-1$ times gives the resulting formula:
$$x!!=(x+1)!\cdot\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)^\frac{x}{2},\ for\ \ \frac{x-1}{2}\in\mathbb{N}$$
Returning once again to our original equation with this newfound knowledge, we can further expand our equation for neither odd $m+n$ nor even $m+n$. This is because both expressions can be rewritten in terms of $\left(\frac{m+n}{2}\right)!$ which *is* our original equation. So, with this in mind we have obtained the following result:
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{m+n}{2}+1\right)=\frac{\left(m+n\right)!!}{2}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2^{m+n+1}}},\ for\ m+n+2\in \mathbb{N}$$
However, you might be able to come up with a similar result by using another formula from  [WolframAlpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) :
$$\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\left(2n-1\right)!!}{2^n}\cdot\sqrt{\pi}$$