# Evaluation of Limit involved in the proof of Asymptotic Unbiasedness of S

Tags: calculus, limits, gamma-function, variance, sampling

We know that $S^{2}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^{2}$ and $S$ is a biased estimator of $\sigma$. But if $n\rightarrow\infty$, then $S$ is an asymptotically unbiased estimator of $\sigma$. I found a proof [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11707/why-is-sample-standard-deviation-a-biased-estimator-of-sigma)(first answer). But in the last step, instead of solving the limit, graphic visualization has been given. Can we somehow algebraically prove that bias$\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$? I was trying to solve with Gamma function definition but couldn't find a suitable formula to apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula would be useful. $$ \Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})=\frac{(2n)!\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2n}n!}$$

Using this, you can show that $\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}} ~ \frac{\Gamma(n/2)}{\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

You can find a proof for the formula [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444967/proving-that-gamma-leftn-frac12-right-frac2n-sqrt-pi22n).

Comment: I tried to solve it doing the substitution $\frac{n-1}{2} = y$. I wasn't able to solve the limit after wards. How to solve afterwards? But I did find a useful limit here:[Proof of formulas for integer or half-integer real part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). I just put $\alpha  = 1/2 $ in the given limit formula.

Comment: In particular, I am unable to remove $\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: @Puneet I use the [Stirling formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) in my calculation. Break the case $n=2k$ and $n=2k+1$ and substitute factorials using $$n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \left( \frac n e \right)^n $$  (Also note that $\Gamma(k)=(k-1)!$) After this, all terms are cancelled in limit.

Comment: Okay! I didn't know much about stirling's formula. Just heard of the name. Thanks.