# Is there a sequence, defined in terms of integers and the basic arithmetic operations such that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} s_n = \pi$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, number-theory

It's a well-known formula that $$
e = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1+1/n)^n
$$
and I'm wondering if there exists a similar formula for $\pi$. All the formulas I know for $\pi$ involve series or products or special functions (such as inverse trig functions). Or one can use Stirling's approximation if factorials are allowed. I'm wondering if there exists a function $F:\mathbb{Z}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $F$ can be written in terms of a finite number of additions, subtractions, multiplications, divisions, and exponentiations, and $$
\pi = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} F(\underbrace{n,n,\cdots,n}_{r \text{ times}},k_1,k_2,k_3,\dots,k_{m-r})
$$
for some fixed integers $m$, $r$, and $k_1,k_2,\dots,k_{m-r}$. In particular, a formula that is defined by a series, infinite product, recursive formula, or continued fraction would not satisfy these conditions.

To be perfectly clear about what I mean, let me formalize. Define a set of elementary sequences $S\subset \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$ as follows: Let $S_0=\{n\}\cup\{\text{all constant, integer-valued sequences}\}$ and define $S_i$ recursively by $$
S_i = \left\{ s_n+t_n,\, s_nt_n,\, (s_n)^{t_n},\, s_n-t_n,\, \frac{s_n}{t_n}\, \mid\, (s_n),(t_n)\in S_{i-1} \right\}.
$$
Then let $S = \bigcup\limits_{i=0}^\infty S_i$. Does there exist a sequence $(s_n)\in S$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} s_n =\pi$?

Note that $(s_n)\in S$ implies $(s_n)\in S_i$ for some finite $i$, which means that each term in the sequence $s_n$ has at most $i$ operations in it. So for example, the sequence $(1+1/n)^n$ is in $S_3$ because it involves 3 operations (one addition, one division, and one exponentiation). A series, such as $s_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k 4}{2k-1}$ is not in $S$ because the number of operations in the $n$th term is unbounded.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80) lists many approximation formulas.  Do any of them meet your requirements?

Comment: No, all of them either involve recursive formulas, infinite sums, or partial fractions, or some other infinite expressions.

Comment: Well $\pi = 16 \arctan \frac{1}{5} - 4 \arctan \frac{1}{239}$ doesn't require recursion, infinite series or products. Why isn't this one acceptable?

Comment: It's not in terms only of the arithmetic operations (including exponentiation)

Comment: What about $F : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(n)=\pi$ for every $n$ ? Then one has $$\pi = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} F(n)$$

Comment: No it has to be defined in terms of the basic arithmetic functions applied to integers.

Comment: "No, all of them either involve recursive formulas, infinite sums, or partial fractions, or some other infinite expressions."  And what's wrong with that?  The formula for $e$ involves a limit with index tending to infinity.  Why is that acceptable but the others aren't? I think you need to be more specific just what conditions you are requiring.

Comment: Updated for clarity

Comment: Another way to define this: is there a **term** $t(n)$ in one free variable $n$, built out of the operations $+,\cdot,-,\div,\mathit{exp}$ and rational constants only, such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}t(n)=\pi$?

Comment: If one allowed the *intermediate* calculations to use complex numbers, then $$\pi=\lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^{1/2} n (1 - (-1)^{1/n})$$ would work. This is a disguised version of $$-i \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^{1/n} - 1}{1/n};$$ the limit is the derivative of $(-1)^x$ evaluated at $x=0$, which is $\log(-1)=i\pi$.

Comment: In fact, building off of @Greg_Martin you can define each term in the sequence such that it is purely real $$s_n=\frac{(-1)^{1/2}n(1-(-1)^{1/n})+(-1)^{-1/2}n(1-(-1)^{-1/n})}{2}=\pi+O(1/n^2)$$ However, there is some ambiguity with your definition of $S$: you say initially that $S\subset \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ but your definition seems to include things such as $i=(-1)^{1/2}$. If the former real only definition, then $s_n$ does not work. But if you take your symbolic definition and allow complex nubmers then $s_n$ works.

Comment: Ah! That is an oversight on my part! Very neat sequence though, I would accept if you post as an answer.

Comment: @QC_QAOA Your $s_n=n\sin(\frac\pi n)$.

Comment: Is square root allowed?

Comment: Yes, because it's $(\cdot)^{1/2}$

Answer (score 4):

Community wiki as it does not satisfy the constrains of the OP:

By [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_%CF%80#Iterative_algorithms) article if you consider the sequence
$$
a_{n+1}=\left(1+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right) a_n
$$
You have
$$
\pi= \lim_n \frac{a_n}{n}
$$
The sequence admits a [closed form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a_0%3D1+%3Ba_%7Bn%2B1%7D%3D+%281%2B1%2F%282n%2B1%29%29+a_n) as
$$
a_n= \frac{\sqrt{\pi} n!}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}
$$
By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444967/proving-that-gamma-leftn-frac12-right-frac2n-sqrt-pi22n) post you can rewrite it as
$$
a_n=\frac{(n!)^22^{2n}}{(2n)!}
$$
So you have
$$
\pi= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n!)^22^{2n}}{n(2n)!}
$$

Comment: The OP's constraints clearly do **not** allow factorial; that said, this is a neat fact. I think it should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber It is too long to be a comment I put it as community wiki

Comment: @NoahSchweber Your criticism is right but I find the OP’s requirement weird if he allows taking $n$-th power in $(1+1/n)^n$ but disallows factorial.