# When a sequence satisfies $a_n= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f_i(n) a_i+ g(n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, generating-functions

**Question**

Given a sequence $a_n$ when it is possible to express such sequence as a "linear recurrence relation with not constant coefficients"? *i.e.* when
$$
a_n= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f_i(n) a_{i} + g(n)
$$
where
$$
f_i(n)=\frac{P_i(n)}{Q_i(n)} r^n
$$
for $P_i, Q_i$ polynomials and $r \in \mathbb{C}$ and also $g(n)$ is the product of a rational function for some geometric sequence.

I'm looking for a characterization for such sequences, but also some necessary condition will be fine.

**Motivation**

There is a complete characterization of the case in which the coefficients are constant (see comments below). In many circumstances using the recursive formula simplify the calculation, so I'm wondering if it is possible to expand this characterization to the case in which the coefficients are not constants

**The conjecture**

Let
$$
F(X):= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}  X^n
$$
and assume that the radius of convergence of the series is not zero.

---

**Conjecture**:  *the sequence can be expressed as a recurrence relation iif $F(X)$ satisfies a linear ODE
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k c_i(X) \frac{d^i}{dX^i}F(X) - g(X)=0
$$
for some $c_i(X), g(X)$ analytic near the origin such that
$$
c^{(k)}_i(0)=\frac{\tilde{P}_i(k)}{\tilde{Q}_i(k)} r^k
$$
with $\tilde{P}_i,\tilde{Q}_i$ polynomials and $r \in \mathbb{C}$ and same for the Taylor coefficients of $g(X)$*

---

The condition is sufficient as $a_n$ satisfies the recurrece relation
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k \left(\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{c_i^{(n-r)}(0)}{(n-r)!r!} a_{r+i}\right) - \frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=0
$$
but i don't know if it is necessary.

Is this condition really necessary? Is there any simpler characterization of such sequences?

Comment: The sequence $a_n$ is a sum of terms each of which is a polynomials in $n$ times a geometric sequence. The set of all such sequences forms a vector space closed under multiplication, i.e., a ring.

Comment: @Somos Is this condition actually necessary? I agree that it is sufficient.

Comment: Yes. One proof uses the dimension of the vector space of such sequences.

Comment: @Somos I think the misunderstanding is in the definition of "closed form" as I can think to at least two counterexamples:

If $$ a_n=\frac{(n!)^22^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$ than [can be shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4866477/is-there-a-sequence-defined-in-terms-of-integers-and-the-basic-arithmetic-opera/4866557#4866557) that the sequence satisfies the relation $$a_{n+1}= \left(1+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)a_n$$. Even more pathological $$ a_k=2^m- \binom{m}{k+1}{}_2F_1(1,k-m+1; k+2; -1)$$$a_{m+k}=a_m$ is not esprimible as elementary function, but is $a_0=1$ $$a_k= a_{k-1}+\binom{m}{k}$$

Comment: I think that the misunderstanding is of "linear recurrence relation". If the coefficients are not constant, all bets are off.

Comment: @Somos i just corrected. I didn't know that linear recurrence relations are supposed to have constant coefficients

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding the question. Given the sequence $a_n$, couldn't you just let $f_i(n)$ be any function, and then let $g(n)=a_n-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f_i(n)a_i$?

Comment: @VarunVejalla  $g(n)$ should not depend on the values $a_i$, but only on $n$

Comment: Right, but let's say you had a sequence $a_n$. For example, let's say you had $a_n=\cos(n)$. Couldn't you let $f_i(n)=n\cdot i$ and let $g(n)=a_n-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}ni\cos(i)$? What do you mean by $g(n)$ shouldn't depend on $a_i$?

Comment: @VarunVejalla I just gave a constrains on the form that the functions can have. This probably cover all the interesting cases, but now it is not always trivially true