# How practical is this formula to calculate $\pi$?

Tags: complex-analysis, pi

So I recently stumbled upon a maths post which caught my eye.
[Here is the link](https://mathforums.com/t/very-easy-way-to-calculate-pi-via-circle-as-a-n-sided-regular-polygon.371176/)

It talked about calculating pi by perceiving the circle as a $n$-sided regular polygon.
Eventually ending up with the limit:
$$π=\lim_{n\to\infty}2in(i^{-\frac{1}{n}}-1) $$
The most straight forward way to compute it would be using euler's formula to calculate it, but that would require knowing $π$ beforehand. Becuase this seems like it could have a lot of potential. Is there any other way to approach computing this?

Comment: Evaluating $i^{-1/n}$ seems tricky to evaluate for larger values of $n$ to me, but I could be completely wrong.


edit: I saw the website link, cool stuff

Comment: Can you estimate it below?

Comment: It computes to pi, that was me using python. But I'm not sure if It has to know $π$ beforehand to calculate, thats the problem

Comment: In sense of squeeze theorem

Comment: The proof from the linked website is very obscure. The identity arises more naturally from $$\pi=\pi\lim_{z\to0}\frac{e^z-1}{z}=\pi\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{\pi/(2ni)}-1}{\pi/(2ni)}=2ni \lim_{n\to\infty}(e^{\pi/(2ni)}-1)=2ni \lim_{n\to\infty}(i^{-1/n}-1).$$ At any rate, it is lacking a way to evaluate $i^{-1/n}$ without using the value of $\pi$ itself.

Comment: The definition of complex exponentiation means that $$i^{-1/n} := \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{k!}\cdot \left(\frac{-\pi i}{2n}\right)^k.$$  It seems all that was done was hiding $\pi$ rather than removing it.  In contrast, using the geometric rather than the analytic trig functions, $\pi = \lim_{n\to\infty} n\sin(\pi/n)$ actually is completely acceptable as a definition of $\pi$ (it's actually a modern incarnation of the historical calculation of $\pi$, using a limit in place of the more classical method of exhaustion)

Comment: @user1551 Kinda interested, where did you find that proof?

Comment: Related question about an elementary limit for $\pi$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4866477)

Comment: If you fix some $k$-gon then proceed by doubling to a $2k$-gon and so on you could modify Archimedes method to calculate the limit without appealing directly to $\pi$. Essentially you're just selecting a subsequence. https://www.craig-wood.com/nick/articles/pi-archimedes/