# Solve the definite integral $\iint_D x^{2n}\,dx\,dy$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Given:$$D=\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 | x^2+y^2 \le 1 \}, n \in \Bbb{N}.$$

**Q1:**
I have to find the definite integral $\iint_D x^{2n} \,dx\,dy$.

$\color{red}{Q2:}$
If $a^2+b^2=1$, then how can we show that the value of the definite integral $\iint_D (ax+by)^{2n} \,dx\,dy$ is independent of $a, b$.

I tried to find the definite integral as follow. But it is difficult.

$$\iint_D x^{2n} \,dx\,dy=\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} x^{2n} \,dy\, dx$$

$$\iint_D x^{2n} \,dx\,dy=\int_{-1}^{1} 2x^{2n} \sqrt{1-x^2} \,dy \,dx$$

Could you please help me to solve Q1 and Q2?

If we use polar coordinates we get

$$\iint_D x^{2n} \,dx\,dy=\int_{0}^{1} r^{2n+1} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \cos^{2n} { \theta} \, d{\theta} \, dr$$

Comment: Heard of polar coordinates?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews do you think your edit was reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

For Q1, use polar coordinates. For Q2, use first the change of variables corresponding to a transformation of the plane that rotates the x-axis to the line ax+by=0.

Comment: I tried to solve this by using polar coordinates, but it didn't work

Comment: Could you please help me to solve Q2?

Comment: First, when using polar coordinates the equation should be $\iint_D x^{2n}dxdy=\int_0^1r^{2n+1}\int_0^{2\pi}cos^{2n}\theta d\theta dr$. The part with cosine can be calculated from this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114755/prove-that-int-cos-x2n-dx-frac-sin-x-cos-x2n-12n-fra using a recurrence formula.

Comment: Could you please help me to solve Q2 ? How to show that the definite integral is independent of $a, b$?

Comment: Have you try to do what I suggested to you? How far have you go?

Comment: I solved Q1. Then I tried to solve Q2 by using binomial coefficients. But I couldn't...

Comment: My suggestion was to try a change of coordinates. Putting $u=ax+by$ and $v=bx-ay$ and changing variables correctly you will obtain: $$\iint_D (ax+by)^{2n}dxdy=\iint_{S}(u)^{2n}dudv.$$ where $S=\{(u,v):u^2+v^2\leq 1\}$, which is the integral of Q1. The hypothesis that $a^2+b^2=1$ will be used several times.

Comment: The answer for Q1 is $$(1.3.5...2n-1) \frac{\pi}{2^n (n+1)!}.$$ So, is the answer for Q2 same as Q1?

Comment: Is it correct to write it as: $\iint_S u^{2n}dudv=\int_0^1r^{2n+1}\int_0^{2\pi}cos^{2n}\theta d\theta dr$.