# How to use integration by parts to solve this question?

Tags: integration

I want so solve the question I found in a textbook in the link http://prntscr.com/afcvur.

(a) Use integration by parts to express
$$I_n(x)=\int\sin^n(x)\,dx$$
in terms of $I_{n-2}(x)$.

(b) Hence show that
$$\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\frac 1{\sin^4(x)}\,dx=\frac 83$$

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The hint is pretty thorough.  What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am not sure how to even approach the question

Comment: Are you familiar with integration by parts?

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114755/prove-that-int-cos-x2n-dx-frac-sin-x-cos-x2n-12n-fra/114765#114765

Comment: I give it a try based on the comments :) thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$$I_n(x) = \int \sin^n (x) \, \mathrm{d} x$$

Integration by parts is:

$$\int u(x)\cdot v(x) \, \mathrm{d} x = uv - \int v \, \mathrm{d} u$$

Using this information let $u = \sin^n(x)$ and let $v = 1$

$$
\begin{align}
\int \sin^n(x) \cdot 1 \, \mathrm{d} x = \sin^n (x) - n \int \cos^{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$

Now, repeat integration by parts so let $u = \cos^{n-1}(x)$ and let $v=1$ for the remaining integral. After repeating the process once or twice, you will notice a pattern where you will be able to substitute $I_n$ and $I_{n-1}$.

Once you have come up with a general form for $I_n(x) = \int \sin^n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ find solution for $I_n(x) = \int^{\pi/2}_0 \sin^n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ and then you will be able to solve your second question.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, we have to compute $$I_n=\int sin^n(x)\,dx$$ Integrate by parts using $$u=\sin^{n-1}(x) \implies u'=(n-1)\sin^{n-2}(x)\cos(x)\,dx$$ $$v'=\sin(x)\,dx \implies v=-\cos(x)$$ So, $$I_n=-\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)+(n-1)\int\sin^{n-2}(x)\cos^2(x)\,dx$$ $$\int\sin^{n-2}(x)\cos^2(x)\,dx=\int\sin^{n-2}(x)(1-\sin^2(x))\,dx=\int\sin^{n-2}(x)\,dx-\int\sin^{n}(x)\,dx$$ The last integral is again $I_n$. So $$I_n=-\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)+(n-1)(I_{n-2}-I_n)$$ $$n I_n=-\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)+(n-1)I_{n-2}$$ and $I_0=x$. You must remember that $I_{-2}$ is pretty simple.